# Ajax won't post form data to PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got a form with some data that needs to be sent and I want to do it with ajax. I got a function that respond on an onclick event of a button. When I click the button I got some post data in firebug but it just doesn't reach my PHP script. Does anyone know what's wrong?

JS:

```
function newItem() {
var dataSet = $("#createItem :input").serialize();


confirm(dataSet); //Below this code box is the output of this variable to check whether it is filled or not

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/earnings.php",
        data: dataSet,
        dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(){
        $('.create_item').children(".row").slideUp('100', 'swing');
        $('.create_item').children("h2").slideUp('100', 'swing');
        confirm("succes");
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        confirm( "Request failed:" + textStatus );
    });
}
```

dataSet result when the form is completly filled in:
`id=123&date=13-09-2013&amount=5&total=6%2C05&customer=HP&invoicenumber=0232159&quarter=1&description=Test`

The PHP:

```
<?php 

    include('includes/dbconn.php');

    function clean_up($string){
        $html = htmlspecialchars($string);
        $string = mysql_real_escape_string($html);
        return $string;
    }

    if($_POST){

        $date = clean_up($_POST['date']);
        $amount = clean_up($_POST['amount']);
        $total = clean_up($_POST['total']);
        $customer = clean_up($_POST['customer']);
        $invoicenumber = clean_up($_POST['invoicenumber']);
        $quarter = clean_up($_POST['quarter']);
        $description = clean_up($_POST['description']);

        $sql = ("INSERT INTO earnings (e_date, e_amount, e_total, e_customer, e_invoicenumber, e_quarter, e_description) 
            VALUES ($date, '$amount', '$total', '$customer', $invoicenumber, $quarter, '$description')");
        echo $sql;
        if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
            echo("Successfully added");
        }else{
            echo "<br /> \n" . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

The form works fine without the ajax but with it it just doesn't work.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: add `print_r($_POST);` check under net>response in firebug

Comment: Double check url path man.. `url: "/earnings.php",`

Comment: The path is right and I can't see a PHP response in firebug since the page does not go to the PHP script but just refreshes the html form.

Comment: how do you call newItem() ? sounds like you're submitting the from before the ajax call

Comment: With `<button onclick="newItem()">Save</button>`.

Comment: Try changing your response data type to "html" I.e. dataType: "html"

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. But thanks for your try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet code bro...

```
<form id="F_login">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="btn_login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

$("#btn_login").click(function(){
    var parm = $("#F_login").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/earnings.php',
        data: parm,
        success: function (data,status,xhr) {
            console.info("sukses");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.info("Error post : "+error);
        }
    });
});
```

Reply me if you try this...

Comment: I got the following error "Error post : [object Object]". This is with serializeArray() and also with serialize().

Comment: check the error using firebug... and,
have you check in your php when this ajax do POST ???

Answer (score 0):

prevent your form submitting and use ajax like this:

```
<form id="createItem">
<input id="foo"/>
<input id="bar"/>
<input type="submit" value="New Item"/>
</form>

$('#createItem).on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault;
newItem();
});
```

Comment: @Tom ok well as I say, to me it sounds like your from is being submitted and the page reloading before your javascript gets a look in. Post your html form and show us how you're calling newItem();

Comment: @Tom ok I didnt see your comment,its typical to use '<input type="submit" value="New Item"/>' at the end of a form, that way pressing return will submit the form which is the expected behavior

Comment: @Tom perhaps try `var dataSet = $("#createItem").serialize();` instead, this assumes your forms id = createItem

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions but without any luck. The page still just refreshes on submit and no data is send to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="foo"/>
<input type="text"  id="bar"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="New Item"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
try
  {
    $.post("my php page address",
      {
         'foo':$("#foo").val().trim(),
         'bar':$("#bar").val().trim()
     }, function(data){
           data=data.trim();
      //   alert(data);
// this  data is data that the server sends back in case of ajax call you 
//can send any type of data whether json or json array or any other type 
//of data

         });
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }
  });


});
</script>
```